# Foundation Top Bar Dropdown z-index issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, z-index

There is a bug in the Foundation 5 framework with the top bar drop down menu when there is an outer wrapper with a class of `contain-to-grid`.

The list items are displayed under other elements such as video and text. The issue goes away once the page is scrolled down a little bit. The z-index has no effect on the menu items.

This seems like a bug. I've done some research and wasn't able to find anyone else with this issue.

Does anyone have the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining the HTML and CSS, it turns out that adding `opacity` to the `contain-to-grid` class causes this bug and sends menu items in back of elements.

Strange how opacity is affecting this. The solution is to remove any opacity if is is applied.